# What charms will be best for study for testscalability/performance

Tags: juju

I have study project and I must test if "more computers" = "more performance" using Juju and MaaS. What charms/services you can recommend me? What will be best solution and easy to check of performance and load.

I tried minecraft but I have problems with this charm(I already post bug). I tried with owncloud but I think it was two separate instance of it.

Thanks of any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've worked on this with hadoop:

- http://markmims.com/cloud/2012/06/04/juju-at-scale.html

But it really depends on what you wanna test.

IMO there are so many things that would scale well using juju, it's hard to pick one in general... here're a few that would be interesting to see:

- hadoop w/ something other than terasort :)
- cassandra
- mongodb
- hive
- lamp (mediawiki for instance)

Please write up your results and post them on the [Juju mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/juju)!

(sorry for the self-link above, but it really is pertinent to your question)

Comment: Generally I want load one computer and check how long it take to do this. After that I want add node and check how long it takes on two computers etc.